# Python Scrapy : How to return nothing if xpath doesn't exist?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

I have this code which scrapes a table with results, the winner is highlighted in a red font and the loser is just text. Here is the [link](http://www.lassen.co.nz/pickandgo.php?fyear=q&teama=NZL#hrh) to the website I'm scraping.
This is how it looks:

```
winner_2 = selector.xpath('.//table[1]/tr[3]/td[4]/font/text()').extract()[0]
loser_2 = selector.xpath('.//table[1]/tr[3]/td[4]/text()').extract()[0]
print (winner_2 + loser_2)
```

This is what comes out:

```
New Zealand v Australia
```

But sometimes there is no winner and no loser (i.e. a tie) and the whole text is just text without a font. In that case, it returns the winner with IndexError: list index out of range (because text with font does not exist) and the loser is both teams, which is what I need.
How can I make it so it checks if a winner exists, and if a winner doesn't exist, then print out the loser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case I would use `extract_first()`:

```
winner_2 = selector.xpath('.//table[1]/tr[3]/td[4]/font/text()').extract_first()
loser_2 = selector.xpath('.//table[1]/tr[3]/td[4]/text()').extract_first()
if winner_2 and loser_2:
    print(winner_2 + loser_2) 
else:
    print(loser_2)
```

This way we avoid the `IndexError`. If any data is missing, it will be `None`, which is logical, I guess.

Comment: Yup, works like a charm. Just need to add to the end `else: print (loser_2)`. Thanks Edit: seems like you already did it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, noticing that split items either end with, or start with, a blank you can do it this way.

```
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get('http://www.lassen.co.nz/pickandgo.php?fyear=q&teama=NZL#hrh').content
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> selector = Selector(text=page)
>>> for item in selector.xpath('.//td[@class="lftblu"]/text()'):
...     if item.extract().startswith(' ') or item.extract().endswith(' '):
...         continue
...     item.extract()
...     
'New Zealand v British Isles'
```